# Can I nest anonymous functions in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I am passing a function to `Enum.reduce` as follows to get `24`

```
Enum.reduce([1,2,3,4], &(&1 * &2)) #=> 24
```

If I have a nested list in which I would like to multiply each nested element and sum them together. For example in `[[1,2],[3,4]]` I would like to perform `[[1*2] + [3*4]]` to get `14`, is there a way to do it (using anonymous functions)

This is what I tried (knowing its incorrect) and I got `nested captures via & are not allowed`. I am trying to understand the required mental model when using Elixir

```
Enum.reduce([[1,2],[3,4]], &(&(&1 * &2) + &(&1 * &2)))
```

Comment: its best not to use `&` operator to create too complex anonyomus functions, since you will end up with hard to debug, understand code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are totally right, if you will try to nest anonymous functions with captures you will get `(CompileError): nested captures via & are not allowed`.

Also, captures are made for simplicity. Do not over-complicate it.

That's how you can do it:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
|> Enum.map(&Enum.reduce(&1, fn(x, acc) -> x * acc end)) 
|> Enum.sum
```

What we do here is basically two things:

1. `Enum.map(&Enum.reduce(&1, fn(x, acc) -> x * acc end))`
   For each sublist (`[1, 2]`, `[3, 4]`) we run a captured function `&Enum.reduce`, where `&1` is the sublist. Then we count the multiplication: `fn(x, acc) -> x * acc end`.
2. We `sum` the result list.

Comment: Hi, could you please briefly describe your solution to clarify my understanding. Thanks.